# Can you help me unmarshall this JSON object into a javabean?

Tags: json, javabeans, jax-rs, jackson

I need to send the following JSON structure to my JAX-RS service.  It's nested a level, if that's the correct term.

```
{
    "catalog" : [
        {"price":"100","sku":"123456"},
        {"price":"120","sku":"1234567"}
    ],
    "customer" : {"name":"joe smith","gender":"male","age":"29"}
}
```

Is what I'm asking possible without writing an adapter?  I guess the trouble comes down to: catalog and customer keys. Does this mean that I need two Javabeans? And the other troublesome part for me is value of the "catalog" key. It's an array of JSON objects.

How do I "beanify" that?

Comment: the json format is incorrect, should be {
"catalog" : [{"price":"100","sku":"123456"},{"price":"120","sku":"1234567"}],
"customer" : {"name":"joe smith","gender":"male","age":"29"}
};

Answer (score 1):

You will need two beans Item and Customer, The item can be aggregated into a list which will create the JSON Array and and customer property is as is. I work mostly with Jackson mapper directly not Jax-rs but it would be something like this.

```
public class Whatever {

    @JacksonProperty
    List<Item> catalog;

    @JacksonProperty
    Customer customer;

    //Getters and Setters

}
```